# php - how to store expiry date in a database and run a (delete) script at date

Tags: php, mysql, date, cron

I have a simple website where users can post ads, i want to set an expiry date based in a mysql table when the user uploads an ad, say in one months time and then when that date is reached then my delete script will be automatically run to remove the ad

any help much appreciated!!

Comment: it may be worth not deleting them but choosing not to show them, you may want\need a record of past adds. In that case you would add a date check to the select *SELECT ... WHERE expires_on <= now()* or *SELECT ... WHERE (added_on + interval 1 MONTH) <= now()*

Comment: thankyou for your reply, i will take this on board! any idea of how i can hide them from a mysql query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add script:

```
INSERT INTO ads (expires_on, ...)
VALUES (now() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH, ...)
```

delete script:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE expires_on <= now()
```

Simply have your delete script run once a day (e.g. cron job)

Comment: thankyou for your reply, could you further explain how are the ads deleted on the date of expiry?

Comment: that's up to you, I'm just showing how'd you code a query to get the ads that are supposed to be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

1. Write a script which queries the database and deletes/flags any expired ads based on a timestamp set when the ad is created.
2. Call this script from a cron job set to run nightly.

Better yet, if the data set is small, ignore the expired ads in your main code instead of deleting them at all.

Comment: thankyou for your reply, this has been useful, will think about ignoring expired ads!

Comment: Don't delete them - just flag them as not live once the expiry date has passed. That way, you can provide historical information amongst other things.

Answer (score 0):

add query:

```
INSERT INTO ads (expires_on, ...)
VALUES (now() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH, ...)
```

delete query:

```
DELETE from ads 
WHERE expires_on <= now()
```

And run them in cron jobs, as others mentioned.